# Can't edit old SSRS reports with Report Builder

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I took over report creation/maintenance at a new job.  We are using SQL Server 2012 and SSRS 2012.  When I try to edit one of the older reports using Report Builder I find I can't even add a comment to some of the code in a dataset without breaking the report.  This particular report has 14 parameters and all I have to do is try to add a comment line (never mind change the code) to a dataset and click OK to close the dataset edit it presents this DEFINE QUERY PARAMETERS prompt to verify the parameters.  If you click OK then all the fields disappear from under the dataset in the Report Data window and the report doesn't work.
Running the report itself without trying to apply any edits still works fine, it's the editing that breaks it. I can edit other previous reports, it's just this particular report that's showing this behavior.

[image]

Comment: Quick follow up, I have seen where other reports I'm working on have presented that DEFINE QUERY PARAMETERS dialog box when I close out of the dataset editing window but that has always been followed up by a message indicating there's an error in the code.  This is the first time I have gotten the PARAMETERS screen but with no indication of coding errors, just a complete loss of the list of fields in the dataset.

Comment: look at the dataset properties and make sure all the parameters are defined properly. Typically you will only see the prompt if a. a parameter value is not defined or b. when there is an error in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured it out after all this time.  The SQL for this dataset has at least a dozen IF-THEN statements spread throughout the code, that keep checking for a certain input parameter that was selected.  I finally simplified the previous report writer's code into one big IF-THEN-ELSE statement and now the dataset can be edited in Report Builder and Visual Studio with no problem.  I'm guessing something changed in Microsoft's SSRS parsing routine between when this report was written in 2018 (where it had no problem with all those IF-THEN statements) and 2020, when the parsing failed but with no helpful error message.